# How can I stop input using ctrl+d in java and eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner, ctrl

I would like to stop my scanner when i am pressing ctrl d. Is this possible?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputTest

{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter String: ");
        String string = input.next();
        System.out.println(string);

        /*If(ctrl + d is pressed){
            scanner.close();
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: It happens automatically. When you press ctrl+D (ctrl+Z on some systems) `System.in` will have end-of-file, and `Scanner.hasNext()` will return false.

Comment: Ctrl-Z for Windows, Ctrl-D for Unix/Linux.